# How many elements in $S$ satisfy $x^2=49 \pmod{5400}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $S=\{0,1,2,...,5399\}$.

How many elements in $S$ satisfy $x^2=49 \pmod{5400}$?

So I'm thinking about using Chinese remainder Theorem, but since $5400$ has many factors, wouldn't cracking it down require too many steps of finding coprime numbers?

Comment: Hint: One solution should be obvious. For the other, consider what the other solution over $\mathbb{Z}$ looks like. To prove that there are only two, see if you can figure out how to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to attack the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $(7,5400)=1$  $$x^2\equiv49\pmod{5400}\iff(x/7)^2\equiv1\pmod{5400}$$

As $5400=100\cdot54=2^33^35^2$

$(x/7)^2\equiv1\pmod{5400}\implies$

$$(x/7)^2\equiv1\pmod{2^3}\iff x/7\equiv1\pmod2$$

$$(x/7)^2\equiv1\pmod{5^2}\iff x/7\equiv\pm1\pmod{5^2}$$

$$(x/7)^2\equiv1\pmod{3^3}\iff x/7\equiv\pm1\pmod{3^3}$$

So, we should have $1\cdot2\cdot2$ in-congruent solutions $\pmod{2\cdot5^2\cdot3^3}$

We can apply [Chinese remainder theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) to find the actual residues

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a mistake, but shouldn't we be looking for congruent solutions mod 2^3⋅5^2⋅3^3 instead of 2⋅5^2⋅3^3?

Comment: @Jingting931015, Multiply the number of solutions with $$\dfrac{2^33^35^2}{3^35^22}=?$$

Comment: Oh I got it! That's right. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jingting931015 You can find many completely solved examples sin [this list.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a242%20crt%20combination)